# Wrong condition for the convergence of the integral $\int_0^\infty t^a \exp(-i t^b) dt$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The integral $\int_0^\infty t^a \exp(-i t^b) dt$ converges for $-1 < a < b - 1$ or $b - 1 < a < -1$.

However,

```
Assuming[Element[a, Reals] && Element[b, Reals],Integrate[t^a Exp[I t^(-b)], {t, 0, Infinity}]]
```

gives

$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[-\frac{e^{-\frac{i \pi  (a+1)}{2 b}} \Gamma \left(-\frac{a+1}{b}\right)}{b},a>-1 ~\&~ a+b<-1\right]$

and

```
Assuming[a < -1 && Element[b, Reals], Integrate[t^a Exp[I t^(-b)], {t, 0, Infinity}]]
```

gives

```
Integrate::idiv: "Integral of E^(I\t^-b)\ t^a does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}.
```

So Mathematica gives wrong results on the convergence of the integral. But for specific choice of a=3/2 and b=3 for which Mathematica says the integral diverges,

```
Integrate[t^(-3/2) Exp[I t^(-3)], {t, 0, Infinity}]
```

gives correct result $\frac{(1+i) \left(\sqrt{3}-i\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{6}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}$. Is it merely a bug or do I miss something?

---

Ok, there are lots of typos in my original question. Here is the polished version.

$\int t^a e^{i t^b} ~dt$ converges for $-1 < a < b-1$ or $b-1 < a < -1$.

Let's see the two cases seprately.

```
Assuming[-1 < a < b - 1, Integrate[t^a Exp[I t^(b)], {t, 0, Infinity}]]
(* (E^((I (1 + a) \[Pi])/(2 b)) Gamma[(1 + a)/b])/b *)
```

This is a correct result.

```
Assuming[b - 1 > a < -1, Integrate[t^a Exp[I t^(b)], {t, 0, Infinity}]]
(* Integrate::idiv: "Integral of E^(I\t^b)\ t^a does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}. " *)
```

This is definitely wrong. However,

```
Integrate[t^(-3/2) Exp[I t^(-3)], {t, 0, Infinity}]
(* ((1 + I) (-I + Sqrt[3]) Gamma[7/6])/Sqrt[2] *)
```

This is contradict to the previous result while correct.

---

Sorry again there is a typo in the code but I cannot edit or make a comment. The second command should be

```
Assuming[b - 1 < a < -1, Integrate[t^a Exp[I t^(b)], {t, 0, Infinity}]]
```

I'm sorry for typos.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: If you must, go [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to have your accounts merged and regain access to your question.

Answer (score 5):

The integral in your Mathematica code is not the same integral as in your image.

```
Integrate[t^a Exp[-I t^b], {t, 0, Infinity}]

(* ConditionalExpression[Gamma[(1 + a)/b]/ (E^((I*(1 + a)*Pi)/(2*b))*b),    
                        Re[a] > -1 && Re[b] > 1 + Re[a] &&  Im[b] == 0] *)
```

Using these stated conditions

```
Assuming[{Re[a] > -1, Re[b] > 1 + Re[a], 
     Im[b] == 0}, Integrate[t^a Exp[-I t^b], {t, 0, Infinity}]]

(* Gamma[(1 + a)/b]/(E^((I*(1 + a)*Pi)/(2*b))*b) *)
```

However, since using a variable in an inequality implies that it is real, these assumptions can be simplified to

```
Assuming[{b - 1 > a > -1}, Integrate[t^a Exp[-I t^b], {t, 0, Infinity}]]

(* Gamma[(1 + a)/b]/(E^((I*(1 + a)*Pi)/(2*b))*b) *)

% == %%

(* True *)
```